# AsyncTask.getStatus() does not return Status.FINISHED

Tags: java, android, xml, post, android-asynctask

I want to start programming Android apps that can communicate with a server to receive/send data and store it on the server.

I have been reading about this and I think I only need to send the data to the server with POST request (perhaps a XML file since I may need to send images), then parse the XML on the server side, and do whatever I need.

To start I'm just trying to send some text through my app.

This is my Post class, for the AsyncTask use:

```
public class Post extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

Context context;
String response;

public Post (Context ctx){
    context = ctx;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://192.168.1.40/index.php");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(false);
        conn.connect();
        String body = "<test>\"some testing\"</test>";

        //Send POST
        OutputStreamWriter output = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(),"UTF8");
        output.write(body);
        output.flush();
        output.close();

        //Get response
        String line = "";
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) sb.append(line);
        response = sb.toString();
        br.close();
        is.close();

        conn.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

public String getResponse(String s)
{

}
```

Using a button to send the request:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Context ctx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ctx = this;
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("Send POST");
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Post p = new Post(ctx);
            p.execute();
            while(p.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED);
            Toast.makeText(ctx,p.getResponse(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.topMargin = 0;
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

    addContentView(b,params);
}
```

And this is my server side php code:

```
<?php print_r($_POST);?>
```

I know there are a lot of posts about this stuff, I went through many of them but I can't figure out this problem.

The HttpURLConnection response code is 200 which means HTTP_OK.

In the index.php page the only output is: "Array ()".

When I debug, the response string is also "Array ()", the problem is that the status of the AsyncTask is "RUNNING" all the time.

P.S - I'm using wampserver as webserver

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I followed Pawel advice and tried this before the Toast:

```
while(p.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED);
```

The app crashed, so I guess it never gets the FINISHED status.

Also tried the AsyncTask.get() method, like this:

```
try {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, p.get().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Got a "false" in the Toast text wich means my p.doInBackground() completed the execution. Why do I still don't have any results?

LAST EDIT: I'm not giving up yet! After a lot of debugging and frustration I think I have found the problem. It was the PHP code! I was expecting it to show me in the browser the post request but It does not work that way apparently.

I changed it to this:

```
    <?php file_put_contents('test.txt', file_get_contents('php://input')); ?>
```

Now I can see the file with the content.

My only problem with this is that if I remove the code to read the response from the server, it does not create the file. Is there something wrong or it's just normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You should read this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You know that `Post` is Asynchronous operation since it extends AsyncTask ? Which means that it can be completed after your invoke `Toast.makeText(ctx,p.getResponse(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

**Small hint:**
Check in above linked documentation about methods:
`public final Result get ()` and `public final AsyncTask.Status getStatus ()`.

Now you should have your results availabe when it is done.

Comment: I have updated my question with the results I've got from your answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Every operation on IO should end with close method to close any connection and stream. Please close HttpUrlConnection, OutputStreamWriter and BufferedReader with proper order. It could be this problem that there is no result present.

Comment: I have thought about that already, but forgot to update de code here. I just edited the original code. The behavior is the same :|. BTW I just found out that the response string inside the AsyncTask is "Array ()". The problem must be with the connection status wich is always "RUNNING". That's why the app was crashing, but how can I make it stop, or finish?